# Get users from db Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get(with js) a list of the users on my db firebase?
I see them stored in "Authentication" and not in "database"
Maybe something like that `FirebaseApp.database().ref('users');` ?

Comment: You need to store the users into the database into something like `users/uid` and then you can use `FirebaseApp.database().ref('users')` to get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you authenticate a user, if you want to other add that user to Firebase Database, you can do this:

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).set({
username: name,
email: email
//some more user data
});
```

then you will have this in the db:

```
users
  useruid
    username: userx
    email: userx@gmail.com
   useruid
    username: usery
    email:usery@gmail.com
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: So i should store in the db? I think firebase do already that don't you think?

Comment: No you need to store them